# Why wont my extension update using composer?

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer

I am trying to update Amasty Layered Navigation. Following their documentation it says to type in the command-

```
composer update amasty/shopby
```

When I do that it says

```
Package "amasty/shopby" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
```

It is installed and functions properly. When I run a status to see if it is enabled it is in there. Am I using the wrong command?

I can see the repo username and password in the auth.json file.

---

**Update:**

The extension was originally installed by ftp, meaning I had to update by using ftp. If anyone knows how to update an extension with composer after installing with ftp I would be curious.

Answer (score 1):

> The extension was originally installed by ftp, meaning I had to update by using ftp. If anyone knows how to update an extension with composer after installing with ftp I would be curious.

Remove the files from `app/code`, then use composer to install the new version:

```
composer require amasty/shopby
```